# Self monitor cache directory

Tags: android, caching, directory

I am currently storing bitmap images inside my cache, each bitmap can be upto 3mb in size each. I am using `getCacheDir()` however, after reading androids documentation, I found this:

> Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space.

So I am considering switching my cache to using `getExternalCacheDir()`, but I am abit uncertain about this:

> The platform does not always monitor the space available in shared storage, and thus may not automatically delete these files. Apps should always manage the maximum space used in this location. Currently the only time files here will be deleted by the platform is when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 or later and isExternalStorageEmulated(File) returns true.

I would like to have full control of the cache dir, because if files are randomly deleted this could really affect the running of my application. I have already set an upper limit for the size of the cache so it will never exceed a certain amount of space. How can I now prevent the system from monitoring and deleting from this cache as it pleases?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think that cache is permanent storage. You mustn't store there files that you rely on. Cache used for storing data that you don't really want to reload or recreate, but you can do it if needed (as with loading pictures from web. Much faster to load from disk, if already done, but can be done without it). If you really depend on this files use `getFilesDir()` this will route you to specific app directory, that wouldn't be erased if no memory (but still can be erased by user in settings). Also, if you have data that is static and you need it always, you must store it in the assets folder, all other data must be considered as temporary (any time user or system can erase it) and checked for existence.

Comment: 2 questions 1) If I use getFilesDir() and stored images here could this still be shown to the user as a media folder? (which I dont want). 2) Can you give me more information about this assets folder?

Comment: 1) Files that stored in getFilesDir are not visible to user (unless he has root access). So user can't delete it easily. But if you want files visible to user, you need getExternalStorageDir(), it's visible to user and can be deleted easily.

Comment: 2) Assets folder used for storing files that will app have always. They will come already with apk file. User can't delete it anyway. But one drawback - you can't place files there dynamically, only before apk building